# Osx Spectrum analyzer/metering standalone

Tags: spectrum

I am looking for a Spectrum analyzer / metering app for osx that can run independent of my DAW on everything i listen to via system audio.

Something that can always sit on a second monitor.

Any recommends?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I like Spectre. I have the Starter pack, it's pretty handy. [App Store Link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/spectre-starter/id436874078?mt=12).

You'll also need Soundflower to help do some internal routing so Spectre can hear the audio before it gets to your monitors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the program 'Audio Hijack Pro'!

It allows to hijack and record any sound source on you mac. So you can Hijack your system audio.

The cool thing with the pro Version is, that you can effect the hijacked audio via VST and AU plug-ins. So you could monitor your main out with any Analyzer you like!